# How can I print recipient mail address in webform email handler body with twig?

Tags: theming, webforms

In the webform e-mail handler configuration I can see that `webform` twig variable is available. I looked to the context with xDebug and it looks like I should be able to print e-mail address of the recipient with in the mail body. But it doesn't work, the body is empty. Do you know why and how can I fix this?

```
{{ webform.handlers.e_mail.settings.to_mail }}
```

Edit: I also tried to use token like this:

```
{{ webform_token('[webform:handler:e_mail:settings:to_mail]', webform_submission, [], options) }}
```

,but the token didn't get replaced.

Answer (score 1):

The module maintainer says it's by design: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3231110